# convert mongo shell query to spring data mongo

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework, spring-mongodb

How do I write the below query in spring data mongo

```
db.MISSING_DATA.aggregate({$group:  { _id: "$FILE_TYPE", abc: {$addToSet: "$REASON"} } });
```

Below is my document

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5edf1776cf566a3c78dc9f90"),
"_class" : "com.loylty.dataacquisition.entities.daEntity.MissingData",
"FILE_TYPE" : "TRANSACTION",
"JSON" : "{\"terminalId\":\"78001205\",\"merchantId\":\"78001205\",\"transactionDate\":1577385000000,\"transactionTime\":\"23:59:57\",\"transactionAmount\":2934.17,\"transactionId\":\"RHMP8350809269\",\"first6DigitCard\":\"512652\",\"last4DigitCard\":\"2419\",\"transactionType\":\"SALE\",\"fileName\":\"POS_08062020_1655.txt\",\"channel\":\"ONLINE_PARTNER\",\"objectType\":\"TRANSACTION\",\"points\":0,\"version\":0,\"merchantName\":\"AJIO\",\"merchantTransactionId\":\"pay_sp_e2180aac-28d6-11ea-83ae-37acfdd9ba94\",\"paymentProcessor\":\"BILLDESK\",\"accountValidated\":false,\"customerValidated\":false,\"binValidated\":false,\"cardValidated\":false}",
"REASON" : "BIN_NOT_RESOLVED",
"MISSING_VALUE" : "512652",
"FILENAME" : "POS_08062020_1655.txt",
"STATE" : "READYTOATTEMPT",
"CHANNEL" : "ONLINE_PARTNER",
"FILE_ID" : "5edf1776cf566a3c78dc9f8f",
"PARENT_PROGRAM_ID" : "40287a35725ae63e017282bd192b0005",
"CREATION_DATE" : NumberLong(1586624062825)
}


 {
"_id" : ObjectId("5edf1a0acf566a3c78dc9f92"),
"_class" : "com.loylty.dataacquisition.entities.daEntity.MissingData",
"FILE_TYPE" : "TRANSACTION",
"JSON" : "{\"terminalId\":\"78001205\",\"merchantId\":\"78001205\",\"transactionDate\":1577385000000,\"transactionTime\":\"23:59:57\",\"transactionAmount\":2934.17,\"transactionId\":\"RHMP8350809269\",\"first6DigitCard\":\"512652\",\"last4DigitCard\":\"2419\",\"transactionType\":\"SALE\",\"fileName\":\"POS_08062020_1655_2.txt\",\"channel\":\"ONLINE_PARTNER\",\"objectType\":\"TRANSACTION\",\"points\":0,\"version\":0,\"merchantName\":\"AJIO\",\"merchantTransactionId\":\"pay_sp_e2180aac-28d6-11ea-83ae-37acfdd9ba94\",\"paymentProcessor\":\"BILLDESK\",\"accountValidated\":false,\"customerValidated\":false,\"binValidated\":false,\"cardValidated\":false}",
"REASON" : "BIN_NOT_RESOLVED",
"MISSING_VALUE" : "512652",
"FILENAME" : "POS_08062020_1655_2.txt",
"STATE" : "READYTOATTEMPT",
"CHANNEL" : "ONLINE_PARTNER",
"FILE_ID" : "5edf19d6cf566a3c78dc9f91",
"PARENT_PROGRAM_ID" : "40287a35725ae63e017282bd192b0005",
"CREATION_DATE" : NumberLong(1586524062825)
 }

{
"_id" : ObjectId("5ee20b5704d6e7344d215830"),
"_class" : "com.loylty.dataacquisition.entities.daEntity.MissingData",
"FILE_TYPE" : "REFUND",
"JSON" : "{\"terminalId\":\"45015967\",\"merchantId\":\"78001205\",\"transactionDate\":1567362600000,\"transactionTime\":\"08:33:03\",\"terminalOwnerName\":\"BATA\",\"transactionAmount\":5000.00,\"transactionId\":\"RHMP8347282554\",\"first6DigitCard\":\"528651\",\"last4DigitCard\":\"3116\",\"transactionType\":\"REFUND\",\"fileName\":\"AJIO_REFUND_1101.txt\",\"channel\":\"AJIO_REFUND\",\"objectType\":\"REFUND\",\"points\":0,\"version\":0,\"merchantName\":\"Reliance Fashion and Lifestyles\",\"merchantTransactionId\":\"pay_sp_dd6374ce-280d-11ea-8cb9-077d78ae9940\",\"partnerProgramId\":\"40287a35725ae63e0172934c765d0014\",\"paymentProcessor\":\"BILLDESK\",\"binValidated\":false,\"cardValidated\":false,\"accountValidated\":false,\"customerValidated\":false}",
"REASON" : "PARTNER_PARENT_TRANSACTION_MISSING",
"MISSING_VALUE" : "528651",
"FILENAME" : "AJIO_REFUND_1101.txt",
"STATE" : "READYTOATTEMPT",
"CHANNEL" : "AJIO_REFUND",
"FILE_ID" : "5ee20b5704d6e7344d21582f",
"PROGRAM_ID" : "ff80808166d37c3a0166d3d9d7520006",
"PARENT_PROGRAM_ID" : "40287a35725ae63e0172934c765d0014"
}

{
"_id" : ObjectId("5ee2151604d6e7344d21588e"),
"_class" : "com.loylty.dataacquisition.entities.daEntity.MissingData",
"FILE_TYPE" : "TRANSACTION",
"JSON" : "{\"terminalId\":\"70020960\",\"merchantId\":\"Ab44bCe8LJQyt4\",\"transactionDate\":1576348200000,\"transactionTime\":\"04:00:49\",\"postDate\":\"17-Dec-2019\",\"terminalOwnerName\":\"AJIO\",\"transactionAmount\":72345,\"transactionId\":\"pay_DsLRZIVDoGwo2C\",\"acquirerId\":\"ratn\",\"first6DigitCard\":\"652203\",\"last4DigitCard\":\"5490\",\"transactionType\":\"SALE\",\"cardTypeCode\":\"RuPay\",\"fileName\":\"POS_110620_Razor.txt\",\"channel\":\"AJIO_ONLINE\",\"objectType\":\"TRANSACTION\",\"points\":0,\"version\":0,\"merchantName\":\"AJIO\",\"merchantTransactionId\":\"DsLRZ5kkX8CWv1\",\"cardIssuer\":\"South Indian Bank\",\"partnerProgramId\":\"40287a35725ae63e0172934c765d0014\",\"paymentProcessor\":\"Razorpay\",\"binValidated\":false,\"cardValidated\":false,\"accountValidated\":false,\"customerValidated\":false}",
"REASON" : "BANK_PARENT_TRANSACTION_MISSING",
"MISSING_VALUE" : "652203",
"FILENAME" : "POS_110620_Razor.txt",
"STATE" : "READYTOATTEMPT",
"CHANNEL" : "AJIO_ONLINE",
"FILE_ID" : "5ee2150c04d6e7344d21588d",
"PROGRAM_ID" : "ff80808166d37c3a0166d3d9d7520006",
"PARENT_PROGRAM_ID" : "40287a35725ae63e0172934c765d0014"
}
```

I tried the below query but not getting desired output.

```
TypedAggregation aggtow =    Aggregation.newAggregation(MissingData.class,
            Aggregation.group("fileType").
                    addToSet("reason").as("reason"),
            Aggregation.project("fileType").
                    and("reason").previousOperation());

    AggregationResults<FileTypeMissingReason> resultss = mongoTemplate.
            aggregate(aggtow, FileTypeMissingReason.class);
    List<FileTypeMissingReason> result= results.getMappedResults();
```

Below is the debug code when I execute my query

**2020-06-15 14:46:14,394 [DEBUG]---[MongoTemplate.java]---[http-nio-8010-exec-3]: Executing aggregation: { "aggregate" : "MISSING_DATA" , "pipeline" : [ { "$group" : { "_id" : "$FILE_TYPE" , "reason" : { "$addToSet" : "$REASON"}}} , { "$project" : { "fileType" : "$_id.fileType" , "_id" : 0 , "reason" : "$_id"}}] , "cursor" : { "batchSize" : 2147483647}}**

*emphasized text*

**FileTypeMissingReason.java**

```
public class FileTypeMissingReason {

private FileType fileType;
private List<MissingReason> reason;

public FileType getFileType() {
    return fileType;
}

public void setFileType(FileType fileType) {
    this.fileType = fileType;
}

public List<MissingReason> getReason() {
    return reason;
}

public void setReason(List<MissingReason> reason) {
    this.reason = reason;
}
}
```

**MISSING.JAVA**

```
@Document(collection = "MISSING_DATA")
public class MissingData {

    @Id
    @Field("_id")
    private String id;

    @Field("FILE_TYPE")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private FileType fileType;

    @Lob
    @Field("JSON")
    private String json;

    @Field("REASON")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private MissingReason reason;

    @Field("MISSING_VALUE")
    private String missingValue;

    @Field("FILENAME")
    private String filename;

    @Field("STATE")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private TransactionState state;

    @Field("CREATION_DATE")
    private Long creationDate;

    @Field("CREATED_BY")
    private String createdBy;

    @Field("LAST_MODIFIED_DATE")
    private Long lastModifiedDate;

    @Field("LAST_MODIFIED_BY")
    private String lastModifiedBy;

    @Field("CHANNEL")
    private String channel;

    @Version
    @Field("VERSION")
    private Integer version;

    @Field("FILE_ID")
    private String fileId;

    @Field("UNIQUE_CUSTOMER_ID")
    private String uniqueCustomerId;

    @Field("PROGRAM_ID")
    private String programId;

    @Field("PARENT_PROGRAM_ID")
    private String parentProgramId;

    public String getFileId() {
      return fileId;
    }

    public void setFileId(String fileId) {
      this.fileId = fileId;
    }

    public MissingData() {
    }

    public String getChannel() {
        return channel;
    }

    public void setChannel(String channel) {
        this.channel = channel;
    }

    public MissingData(Transaction transaction, MissingReason reason) {
        this.json = transaction.toString();
        this.filename = transaction.getFileName();
        this.fileType = transaction.getObjectType();
        this.reason = reason;

    }

    public MissingData(MissingReason reason, FileType fileType) {
        this.reason = reason;
        this.fileType = fileType;
    }


    @PrePersist
    public void insertDateforLoylty() {
        this.creationDate = System.currentTimeMillis();
        this.lastModifiedDate = creationDate;
        //   this.id = creationDate;
    }

    @PreUpdate
    public void updateDateforLoylty() {
        this.lastModifiedDate = System.currentTimeMillis();
        //    version = version + 1;
    }

    public MissingReason getReason() {
        return reason;
    }

    public void setReason(MissingReason reason) {
        this.reason = reason;
    }

    public String getFilename() {
        return filename;
    }

    public void setFilename(String filename) {
        this.filename = filename;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public FileType getFileType() {
        return fileType;
    }

    public void setFileType(FileType fileType) {
        this.fileType = fileType;
    }


    public TransactionState getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(TransactionState state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public Long getCreationDate() {
        return creationDate;
    }

    public void setCreationDate(Long creationDate) {
        this.creationDate = creationDate;
    }

    public String getCreatedBy() {
        return createdBy;
    }

    public void setCreatedBy(String createdBy) {
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }

    public Long getLastModifiedDate() {
        return lastModifiedDate;
    }

    public void setLastModifiedDate(Long lastModifiedDate) {
        this.lastModifiedDate = lastModifiedDate;
    }

    public String getLastModifiedBy() {
        return lastModifiedBy;
    }

    public void setLastModifiedBy(String lastModifiedBy) {
        this.lastModifiedBy = lastModifiedBy;
    }

    public Integer getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(Integer version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    public String getJson() {
        return json;
    }

    public void setJson(String json) {
        this.json = json;
    }

    public String getUniqueCustomerId() {
        return uniqueCustomerId;
    }

    public void setUniqueCustomerId(String uniqueCustomerId) {
        this.uniqueCustomerId = uniqueCustomerId;
    }

    public String getMissingValue() {
        return missingValue;
    }

    public void setMissingValue(String missingValue) {
        this.missingValue = missingValue;
    }

    public String getProgramId() {
        return programId;
    }

    public void setProgramId(String programId) {
        this.programId = programId;
    }

    public String getParentProgramId() {
        return parentProgramId;
    }

    public void setParentProgramId(String parentProgramId) {
        this.parentProgramId = parentProgramId;
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add into set `$$ROOT` variable

```
db.MISSING_DATA.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$FILE_TYPE",
      fileType: {
        $first: "$FILE_TYPE"
      },
      reason: {
        $addToSet: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      "reason._class": 0
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Bm504JiHTHT)

#### Spring-mongo implementation

```
Aggregation.newAggregation(Aggregation.group("fileType").
    addToSet("$$ROOT").as("reason").first("FILE_TYPE").as("fileType"),
Aggregation.project().
    andExclude("_id", "reason._class"));
```

Comment: actually I edited my question , spring  version issue got solved

Comment: @MuddassirRahman Post please sample data, field name mismatch with shell query and Java implementation

Comment: check my latest edits . I have added the shell query which spring is creating

Comment: @MuddassirRahman Provide please a sample data (any example of MISSING_DATA collection)

Comment: @MuddassirRahman Nice. One more thing: Provide `MissingReason` class definition

Comment: I just checked inside raw result I am getting output but not in mappedResult

Comment: @MuddassirRahman Forgot to ask you share `FileType` definition.

Comment: filetype is ENUM

Comment: @MuddassirRahman check my answer, it should work now

Comment: reason.class FileTypeReason ?

Comment: @MuddassirRahman what do you mean with "reason.class FileTypeReason"?